# Drawing using Windows 7 theme

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-7, custom-controls

I am currently working on a custom combobox. At the moment I am inheriting from Combobox but this I find unsatisfactory. It gives me a lot of functionality that I then need to hide and has some annoying behavours. I would much prefer to use a textbox and just draw a dropdown button on the textbox. This would not only allow me to draw the button anywhere I want but also get rid of all the stuff I don't need or want.

What I need to do is draw the button using Windows 7 themes. `ComboBoxRenderer`, as far as I know, uses XP styles which I don't want. `ToolStripItemRenderer` was not useful for this as far as I could tell.

How do I draw the button without using a third party library

Thanks for any help
Danny

Comment: Could you either) use a real button or) tell an invisible real button to [drawToBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) itself and use that bitmap?

Comment: Thanks for the idea TaW but this doesn't really work for what I wish to do.

Comment: Have you looked into the [VisualStyleRenderer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/system.windows.forms.visualstyles.visualstylerenderer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: TaW I have descided to go with your first comment and use a real button. The more I thought about it the more freedom I saw this giving me. Thanks